# merging different models into sealed class

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I’m writing PC app using Kotlin and TornadoFX.

I’ll show you what I have

`FooModel.kt`:

```
class FooModel(val id: Int){
    constructor(foo: Foo) : this(foo.id)
}
```

`Foo.kt`:

```
data class Foo(val id: Int)
```

`MainController.kt`:

```
val FoosList: ObservableList<FooModel> = FXCollections.observableArrayList<FooModel>()

//bellow I wanna describe what I’m already doing with val above

fun fooDifferentOperationsForExample(example: Int){
    example1Object = FoosList.find{ it.id == example }
    example2Object.removeIf { it.id == example }
    example3Object.setAll(it.map {FooModel})
}
```

I’m showing described `model` in listview and want to add objects of another kind(s) in the same list. I have a solution with `sealed class`, example of `DifferentKindsOfInstances.kt`:

```
sealed class DifferentKindsOfInstances{
    data class Foo(val foo: FooModel): DiffrentKindsOfInstances()
    data class Bar(val bar: BarModel): DiffrentKindsOfInstances()
}
```

let’s think `BarModel` is exact copy of `FooModel`, nevermind.

But if I wanna continue working with FooModel in a way I worked before(in `MainControl`) - how would the code look then?

`it.foo.id` doesn’t work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that references the sealed class members in two places: rendering the ListCell in cellFragment{} and in the binding of the selected sealed class item to the textfield string content.

```
class ItemModel1 ( val dataField1 : String )
class ItemModel2 ( val dataField2 : String )

sealed class ItemViewInstance {
    data class Item1(val item1: ItemModel1): ItemViewInstance()
    data class Item2(val item2: ItemModel2): ItemViewInstance()
}

class SealedClassDemoView : View("Sealed Class") {

    val instances = listOf(
            ItemViewInstance.Item1(ItemModel1("One")),
            ItemViewInstance.Item2(ItemModel2("Two"))
    ).observable()

    val selectedItemString = SimpleStringProperty()

    override val root = vbox {
        listview(instances) {
            cellFormat {
                when( it ) {
                    is ItemViewInstance.Item1 -> text = it.item1.dataField1
                    is ItemViewInstance.Item2 -> text = it.item2.dataField2
                }
            }

            selectedItemString.bind(
                    Bindings.createStringBinding(
                        Callable  {
                            val sel = selectionModel.selectedItemProperty().value
                            when (sel) {
                                is ItemViewInstance.Item1 -> sel.item1.dataField1
                                is ItemViewInstance.Item2 -> sel.item2.dataField2
                                else -> ""
                            }
                        },
                        selectionModel.selectedItemProperty()
                    )
            )
        }
        textfield(selectedItemString)
        padding = Insets(2.0)
        spacing = 4.0
    }
}

class SealedClassDemoApp : App(SealedClassDemoView::class)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    launch<SealedClassDemoApp>(args)
}
```